# Populate a dataframe column using a function that applies an equation to a reference table

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

Suppose you want to calculate how far away a patient's BMI is away from the population median using a Z-score. This is calculated using the patient's BMI plus three age- and sex-dependent variables. These three variables are looked up in a table.

So, I created a function that takes age, sex, and BMI as inputs. It uses sex to find the appropriate table (male or female), age to find the appropriate row in that table, and then BMI in a calculation that incorporates the age- and sex-specific variables you just looked up. My function works when I enter the data manually into the function, **but what I can't figure out is** how to iteratively go through each row in the data-frame to apply my function, using other row-specific columns in the data frame as inputs.

For the sake of simplicity, I just use two age- and sex-dependent variables below (median BMI and then a multiplier)

```
### make master dataframe
study_id <- c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005)
age <- c(4, 3, 3, 1, 5)
sex <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1)
df <- tibble(study_id, age_df, sex)

### reference male table
age_m <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
median_bmi_m <- c(14.9, 16.3, 16.9, 17.2, 17.3)
multiplier_m <- c(22, 23, 43, 11, 33)
reference_male <- tibble(age_m, median_bmi_m, multiplier_m)

### reference female table
age_f <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
median_bmi_f <- c(15.9, 17.3, 17.9, 18.2, 18.3)
multiplier_f <- c(12, 13, 33, 21, 23)
reference_female <- tibble(age_f, median_bmi_f, multiplier_f)

### my function
toy_function <- function(age, sex) {
  if(sex == 1) {
    a <- reference_male[age, 2]
    b <- reference_male[age, 3]
    c <- a*b
  } else {
    a <- reference_female[age, 2]
    b <- reference_female[age, 3]
    c <- a*b
  }
  return(as.numeric(c))
}
```

The function returns a numeric value "c" that I want to apply row-wise to each patient. I built a FOR loop that does it, but I'm thinking there is a more elegant way using purrr or apply() functions. I tried simply sticking the function inside of mutate, but I get an error.

```
df <- df %>%
   mutate(new column = toy_function(age, sex)

Error in toy_function(age_df, sex) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
In addition: Warning message:
In if (sex == 1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Thanks for you help. I still haven't quite gotten a good handle on purrr and other row-wise iteration strategies.

**UPDATE**

Thanks all for the answers. While the offered solution to the original toy example worked, when I went back to my original more complex function (with three inputs instead of two), I am getting an error message.

Suppose we update the function and original dataframe to incorporate BMI as so:

```
### updated dataframe with BMI variable
study_id <- c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005)
age <- c(4, 3, 3, 1, 5)
sex <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1)
bmi <- c(15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
df <- tibble(study_id, age_df, sex, bmi)

### updated function with bmi variable incorporated into the equation

toy_function <- function(age, sex, bmi) {
  if(sex == 1) {
    a <- reference_male[age, 2]
    b <- reference_male[age, 3]
    c <- a*b*bmi
  } else {
    a <- reference_female[age, 2]
    b <- reference_female[age, 3]
    c <- a*b*bmi
  }
  return(as.numeric(c))
}
```

When I run the solution code as such, I get the following error:

```
df %>%
  mutate(new_column = map2_dbl(age, sex, bmi, ~ toy_function(..1, ..2, ..3)))

Result 1 must be a single double, not NULL of length 0
```

It appears that there is something that I'm doing incorrectly as I add in the third variable. Note: I read that the `..1`, `..2`, `..3` syntax may be preferred when you have multiple variables in the function, but I may be mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to use `rowwise` function before mutate here:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new_column = toy_function(age, sex))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Rowwise: 
  study_id   age   sex new_column
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1001     4     1       189.
2     1002     3     1       727.
3     1003     3     2       591.
4     1004     1     2       191.
5     1005     5     1       571.
```

Or if you would like to do it with `purrr` you can use the following code. Here since this is a row-wise operation `.x` value refer to the corresponding value of variable `age` in every row and `.y` refers to the corresponding value of variable `sex` in every row:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_column = map2_dbl(age, sex, ~ toy_function(.x, .y)))

# A tibble: 5 x 4
  study_id   age   sex new_column
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1001     4     1       189.
2     1002     3     1       727.
3     1003     3     2       591.
4     1004     1     2       191.
5     1005     5     1       571.
```

Or in base R:

```
cbind(mapply(\(x, y) toy_function(x, y), df$age, df$sex) |>
        as.data.frame() |>
        setNames("new_column"), df)
```

**Updated Solution**
It should be noted that since we are iterating over more that 2 variables here, we require to use `pmap` instead of `map2`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(new_column = pmap_dbl(., ~ toy_function(..2, ..3, ..4)))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
  study_id   age   sex   bmi new_column
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1001     4     1    15      2838 
2     1002     3     1    16     11627.
3     1003     3     2    17     10042.
4     1004     1     2    18      3434.
5     1005     5     1    19     10847.
```

Or if you wanna stick by your solution just exclude the first variable in `.l` argument of `pmap`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(new_column = pmap_dbl(df[-1], ~ toy_function(..1, ..2, ..3)))
```

And with `pmap` we don't need `rowwise` to emphasis a row-wise operation as specified in the documentations:

> Note that a data frame is a very important special case, in which case
> pmap() and pwalk() apply the function .f to each row.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks. I think I need to just sit down one day and really study the purrr strategies.

Comment: You're welcome. That's a great idea as you will realize they are extremely useful in solving almost every kind of problem.

Comment: Yes agreed. I'm actually having a little difficulty as I add a third variable into the function (as is the case with my real-life problem). I've updated the toy example above to re-create the error.

Comment: @Casey I added another solution to take your third variable into account. The only problem with you solution is you chose first variable which is `study_id` with `..1` whereas our required variables are `..2` to `..4` in your data set.

Comment: This is great. And now 32,000 bmi z-scores are known to science. Thanks again - C

Comment: Glad it help. If you have any question regarding `purrr` or these solutions, you can ask anytime. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

As the function was constructed with `if/else` which are not vectorized, we could convert the function to `Vectorize`d one and apply

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(new_column = Vectorize(toy_function)(age, sex))
```

-ouptut

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  study_id   age   sex new_column
     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1001     4     1       189.
2     1002     3     1       727.
3     1003     3     2       591.
4     1004     1     2       191.
5     1005     5     1       571.
```

Comment: The non-vectorized nature of if/else is new to me. Thanks for the introduction to the Vectorize() function. Cheers.